# How many processes are forked here

Tags: c, process, fork

I know that it might come as a stupid question but could anyone help me understand the behavior of the following code snippet

```
//label 0
int main(){
  fork();//label 1
  fork();//label 2
  fork();//label 3
  return 0;
}
```

As far as I understand, the process tree goes like this

```
              [0]
          /    |    \
        [1]   [2]   [3]
       /  \    |
      [2] [3] [3]
       |
      [3]
```

Am I right?
In case so, I am confused as to why the second fork doesn't spawn a process corresponding to label 1 fork and the third fork doesn't spawn any process any further. I mean a child process is the exact copy of the parent (at least in code) so it must execute the code of its parent in entirety. Can anyone please help me with this confusion...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the child is a copy of its parent. It inherits execution state too, including *where* in the code the parent was executing. When the parent returns from the first fork() with the PID (>0)  of the child, its first child returns with 0 and then continues on to the second and third forks.  The child doesn't go back to the top of main(), it just goes on from after the fork that created it.

**EDIT** Re-word in response to comment. See the [fork(2) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) for the meaning of all return values.

Comment: @Wooble Good point. I will edit my answer to make sure that is clear.

Comment: @JohnW.O'Brien is there a way to get the forked process start execution from the beginning... just curious. I know it will result in an infinite loop. Just thought I could use forking instead of recursion for some problems ;)

Comment: @sidharthsharma You would need to check the return from fork(), and upon discovering that you are executing as the child, implement some control flow to go back to the beginning. Alternatively, you could exec() yourself after forking, which definitely starts from the beginning, but doesn't preserve other state. **EDIT** exec() without fork() isn't very useful.

Answer (score 3):

After the first fork, you have two processes. Both hit the second fork, creating four processes in total.

All four hit the third fork, so you have eight processes. Then they all exit.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple there are total 8 process in parallel.

```
p ----------------
|                 |          // first fork() 
1c-------         p -------   
|        |        |        |      // second fork()
2c---    1c---    3c---    p----  
|   |    |    |   |    |   |    |    // third fork()
4c  2c   1c   5c  6c  3c   7c   p
```

You can count the leaf nodes which is `8` so total 8 processes.

Explanation : parent `p` called `fork()` 2 process `1c` first child and parent `p`.Now the second `fork()` is for both the processes. so the process `1c`,`2c`,`3c`,`p`.
So on and you get 8 processes after third `fork()` call.
After fork new process executes just after the code where it is forked. so all the code below the fork is for both parent and the child processes.

Comment: is there a way to get the forked process start execution from the beginning... just curious. I know it will result in the creation of infinite processes

Comment: from the beginning means (of) what ? anyway you need a process which will call the `fork()` function and then create a new process. Please be little clear and specific ?

Comment: by beginning I am implying from the main() itself... @John W. O'Brain explains that the forked process inherits the execution state of the parent process, so it will start execution form the point where `fork()` is called. I want to know if somehow it can start execution from the `main()`...

Comment: since it copies the whole process control block `PCB` including program counter status.hence execution starts from just below the fork statement.So, if you want, then you will have to set the program counter to the specific address location from where you want to start.

Answer (score 0):

The process tree looks like below. I used following naming convention for processes. prefix parent process name to the corresponding fork label that created it.

```
                [0]
          /      |      \
        [01]    [02]    [03]
       /  \       |
    [012] [013] [023]
     /
   [0123]
```

Like @Mat said, 8 processes are created.

Comment: @sidharthsharma Because you have three unconditional `fork()`s, and each `fork()` doubles the number of processes (unless it fails). `2³ = 8`.