# trouble understanding fork() in c

Tags: c

I know `fork()` will create a child and `for loop` will repeat the `fork()` for each child. But I don't know why I get 7 children processes for 3 times repeat.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    printf("Process PID %6d \t PPID %6d \n",
    getpid(), getppid());
    for (i = 0; i<3; ++i)
    {
        if (fork()==0)
        printf("Process PID %6d \t PPID %6d \n", getpid(), getppid()); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone explain about this coding

Comment: Short answer: The children will fork too. Longer answer forthcoming.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13730554/694576

Comment: sorry for repeated the question but  I not find that question before because of its title are miss understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's walk through the steps:
*(Note that the order of steps is not set in stone (a child could fork before its father forks again), but that doesn't change the cause/effect relationship, so I'll just assume an arbitrary order that makes it easier to explain)*

- At first, you have one process (let's call it process #42)
- It forks: You now have two processes, that have both finished the first iteration:

  - Process #42, past first iteration
  - Let's call it process #43, son of #42, past first iteration
- Process #42 does its second iteration and forks again: You now have three processes:

  - Process #42, past second iteration
  - Process #43, son of #42, past first iteration
  - Process #44, son of #42, past second iteration
- Process #42 does its third iteration and forks one last time: You now have four processes:

  - Process #42, past third iteration
  - Process #43, son of #42, past first iteration
  - Process #44, son of #42, past second iteration
  - Process #45, son of #42, past third iteration (will not fork)
- Now that process #42 is done forking, let's see what happens to its sons:
- Process #43 does its second iteration and forks "again" (actually its first time, but it will only fork twice): You now have five processes:

  - Process #42, past third iteration
  - Process #43, son of #42, past second iteration
  - Process #44, son of #42, past second iteration
  - Process #45, son of #42, past third iteration (will not fork)
  - Process #46, son of #43, past second iteration
- Process #43 does its third iteration and forks one last time: You now have six processes:

  - Process #42, past third iteration
  - Process #43, son of #42, past third iteration
  - Process #44, son of #42, past second iteration
  - Process #45, son of #42, past third iteration (will not fork)
  - Process #46, son of #43, past second iteration
  - Process #47, son of #43, past third iteration (will not fork)
- Process #44 does its third iteration and forks one first and last time: You now have seven processes:

  - Process #42, past third iteration
  - Process #43, son of #42, past third iteration
  - Process #44, son of #42, past third iteration
  - Process #45, son of #42, past third iteration (will not fork)
  - Process #46, son of #43, past second iteration
  - Process #47, son of #43, past third iteration (will not fork)
  - Process #48, son of #44, past third iteration (will not fork)
- And finally, Process #46 does its third iteration and forks one first and last time too. You should now have eight processes, seven of which are children:

  - Process #42, past third iteration
  - Process #43, son of #42, past third iteration
  - Process #44, son of #42, past third iteration
  - Process #45, son of #42, past third iteration (will not fork)
  - Process #46, son of #43, past third iteration
  - Process #47, son of #43, past third iteration (will not fork)
  - Process #48, son of #44, past third iteration (will not fork)
  - Process #49, son of #46, past third iteration (will not fork)

That makes eight processes total, seven of which children, four of which won't fork at all.

Comment: thank for the explanation

Answer (score 8):

Let me draw a tree figure.

```
parent i=0
fork() -------------------------------------v
parent i=1                                  child1 i=1
fork() ---------------v                     fork() ---------------v
parent i=2            child2 i=2            child1 i=2            child2 i=2
fork() ----v          fork() ----v          fork() ----v          fork() ----v
parent i=3 child3 i=3 child2 i=3 child3 i=3 child1 i=3 child3 i=3 child2 i=3 child3 i=3
           1          2          3          4          5          6          7
```

Therefore there are 7 children created.

Answer (score 0):

Very simplified:

Where `=>` denotes `fork`ing.

```
parent => (child-1), (child-2), (child-3)
           child-1 => (child-11), (child-12)
                       child-11 => (child-111)
                      child-2 => (child-21)
```